# opening two dialog box at same time in android

Tags: android

i want to take android runtime permissions on the click of Ok button in alert box in my app.since on requesting permissions we have standard alert box displayed which asks user for permissions ,i want that after user deny/allow permission the 1st dialog box will reappear how will i do it?

Comment: Please add your code so far

Comment: You can do `dialog.show();` right?

Comment: u need not to write any customized dialog box for android Runtime permissions http://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/

Comment: Follow above link i think it's help's you

Comment: @jayeshsolanki93 i have already tried that bt it wont display the previous dialog box

Comment: What does that meaning of previous dialog Please post code what your wrote and make sentence formation clearly